# How to disable "Test Source Xref"

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm using Maven Site Plugin to generate my project page. I want to publish sources also. So I used JXR Plugin. Does anybody know if it is possible to disable "Test Source Xref" report. I've only found this page http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JXR-47 but this parameter doesn't seem to be working.
My configuration in POM looks like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2</version>
<configuration>
<reportPlugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <suppressTestXref>true</suppressTestXref>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</reportPlugins>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppressTestXref is not available anymore. The way to do this is:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <reporting>
     ...
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>jxr</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
```

AFAIK this is not documented anywhere :)